# $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges as well

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> We have two positive series: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ and we know that: $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ (from a certain index). Show that if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ converges then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges as well.

I think I know how to do it with contrapositive (suppose $a_n$ diverges, show it's bounded by $b_n$ thus it can't diverge) but I don't know how to show that $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \le \frac {b_{n+1}}{b_n} \Rightarrow a_n \le b_n \ \forall n$.

Comment: See Theorem 3, [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.westga.edu%2F~faucette%2Fresearch%2FRaabe.pdf&ei=pYBWU-XgEsuayASJs4G4Bg&usg=AFQjCNFkLkOdZ4RGNIQF9Id2lDbpJpzMoQ&bvm=bv.65177938,d.aWw&cad=rja).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac {a_{j+1}}{a_j} \le \frac {b_{j+1}}{b_j}$$
$$\log{a_{j+1}}-\log{a_{j}} \leq \log{b_{j+1}}-\log{b_{j}} $$
Sum from $j=1..n$:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\log{a_{j+1}}-\log{a_{j}} \leq \sum_{j=1}^n\log{b_{j+1}}-\log{b_{j}} $$
$$\log{a_{n+1}}-\log{a_{1}} \leq \log{b_{n+1}}-\log{b_{1}} $$
Take exponential:
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1}\leq \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_1}$$
And you have your result.

Answer (score 3):

If $M > 0$ and $a_n \le M b_n$, then $a_{n+1} \le \dfrac{a_n b_{n+1}}{b_n} \le M b_{n+1}$. You can use the comparison test.